# Using multiple button to start different activities Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have  3 activities. Main activity which is the home screen with two buttons, each button should show up one of the 2 last activity. I tried many methods for multiple buttons both in intent mode and switch mode; but I still can have two working button. The first button starts its linked activity without any problem, but the second button still won't show up. Here is the java code:

```
package com.live.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    Button button01;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WoneWideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton2() {

        final Context context = this;

        button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);

        button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }

}
```

The main layout file content:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ..........................
..............................
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/live_button" 
         android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/vod_button" 
         android:onClick="onClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also I have all these activities/class declared in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to call `addListenerOnButton2()`. Anyhow You can make your code simple

Try This:

```
     Button btn1,btn2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);

}

public void onClick(View v){

    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonUrl){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WoneWideo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   

    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.button01){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I changed context into getBaseContext to get it work.

Answer (score 2):

When there is a property `android:onClick="onClick"` in your xml, then there is **no need for setting listeners**. Only thing you need is, a function with signature `public void onClick(View v){}`

So, the Activity will be as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void onClick(View v){

switch(v.getId()){
 case R.id.buttonUrl:
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WoneWideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);   
break;
case R.id.button01:
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nizam. It simply the code. I chann*ged this line to get it work :  intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WebViewActivity.class);

Comment: You are welcome. That was a mistake while copy-paste. Actually it was `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `addListenerOnButton2()` in `onCreate()`. You only called `addListenerOnButton()`